# Custom text style drawing in an NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How would I go about drawing an NSTextView's text to look similar to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCuWW.png

I would normally use an NSAttributedString but I can't produce the rounded stroke properly.

I have code that converts an NSString to an NSBezierPath which works, but I am unsure how to draw it in an NSTextView.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For custom drawing in an NSTextView, you will need to subclass NSLayoutManager and handle the drawing there. What you want to do won't be easy, though, I don't think. I've subclassed NSLayoutManager in the past to draw extra marks behind characters and between characters, but you will actually need to draw the affected ranges of text yourself, by overriding -drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:. You can use the range passed in, convert it to a character range using -characterRangeForGlyphRange:actualGlyphRange:, and check the characters in the range are ones to which you wish to apply your custom drawing. For such ranges, you'll do the drawing yourself. The tricky part will be ensuring your string is drawn at the right location, taking into consideration line spacing and such. -lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:... and -locationForGlyphAtIndex: should be your friends here.